Why does UIImageView and SwiftUI Image have different resizing techniques?
I've noticed that UIImageView and SwiftUI Image have different resizing techniques. In SwiftUI, the image resizes as I would expect by taking up the full 200x200 frame. The UIKit view does not. There's some padding at the top and bottom of the chevron. How can I get it to behave like the SwiftUI version?
This also happens when using a more square image such as "car.circle". The "car.circle" image size in UIKit is reported as (19.666666666666664, 19.0) and the chevron as (12.666666666666666, 16.666666666666664). If you use a perfectly square image such as 1400x1400 this issue does not occur.
Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    .background(Color.orange.opacity(0.3))

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let container = UIView()
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        container.backgroundColor = .systemOrange.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        
        let chevronLeft = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")!
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = chevronLeft
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        container.addSubview(imageView)
        view.addSubview(container)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            container.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            container.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            container.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        ])
    }
}

UIKit (left) vs SwiftUI (right)


